# ValidateOnDataErrors по признаку из модели представления

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, валидация

Есть базовая модель представления, которая реализует `IDataErrorInfo` и складывает результаты валидации в коллекцию, содержимое которой показывается на экране.

Есть наследник, на свойство которого навешен атрибут валидации.

```
public sealed class MainVm : ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool ValidateProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Проблема в том, что решение о выполнении/не выполнении валидации мне нужно принимать в зависимости от значения свойства `ValidateProperties`. Сейчас у меня в разметке примерно следующий код:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```

А мне нужно что-то вроде этого (но так делать WPF не позволяет):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors={Binding ValidateProperties}}"/>
```

Как можно добиться такого поведения, чтобы валидация выполнялась в зависимости от значения свойства?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал следующее решение:
В базовую модель представления был добавлен метод, который проверяет нужно ли выполнять валидацию для указанного свойства:

```
protected virtual bool CanValidateProperty(string propertyName)
{
    return true;
}
```

В результате чего индексатор `IDataErrorInfo` приобрел следующий вид:

```
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            // если нужно выполнять валидацию - выполняем и возвращаем результат
            if (CanValidateProperty(columnName))
            {  
                return Validate(columnName);
            }

            // очищаем прошлые результаты валидации и возвращаем пустую строку
            RemoveValidationResults(columnName);
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

В модели представления наследника переопределяем `CanValidateProperty` и следим за тем, чтобы текст обновлялся при обновлении признака того, что нужно выполнить валидацию:

```
public sealed class MainVm : ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool ValidateText
    {
        get { return validateText; }
        set
        {
            if (validateText != value)
            {
                validateText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // обновляем текст
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
            }
        }
    }
    private bool validateText;

    protected override bool CanValidateProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        // валидация текста зависит от значения свойства ValidateText
        if (propertyName == nameof(Text))
        {
            return ValidateText;
        }

        return base.CanValidateProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Код в разметке не изменился:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
```